# ionic build android give me an error at :CordovaLib:compileDebugJavaWithJavac point

Tags: android, ionic-framework

i built an ionic app and i need to emulate it on android at the first time .strong text
i set the **path** and **ANDROID_HOME** variables as ionic need and add android platform. but when i run the command `ionic build android` it give me the shown error .
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XhfsD.png)

Answer (score 0):

`requestPermissions()` is availble in the [API Level 23](http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html). Please make sure you've installed all the required packages (from the Android SDK Manager) on your system. 
You'll probably have to check your config.xml too, the value of target SDK version (`preference` with `name="android-targetSdkVersion"`) has to be **23** (`value="23"`).

Comment: i change the target to become 22 since i don't have 23 SDK

Comment: Why don't you want to install API 23 ? It includes new features involved in Android 6+ "runtime permissions" (just a question, though, no offense)

Comment: I'm downloading it but it need long time so i change the target to 22 until it downloaded   :)

Comment: ok. Just FYI, unless you plan to target the specific devices, you don't need to download the "system images" of "Android TV" nor Intel CPU's. It will save some time !

Comment: i download the 23 SDK and my app work correctly , thank you very much

Comment: You're welcome! Could you please validate/upvote my answer? Thus your question will be marked as Answered. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please try command;

```
ionic platform remove android
ionic platform add android
ionic platform build android --debug
```

Comment: it give me : 
[https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1wMCZ0y0ZiTcEdUZWJLelloMjg/view?usp=sharing]

Comment: try command : ionic platform add android - https://github.com/agileek/docker/issues/2